# How does the Visual Studio watch window know to expand `std::vector<T>` and show the elements?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

If you expand a `std::vector<T>` in the watch window, you'll get items like "[0]", "[1]" etc, one for each value in the collection.

When implementing my own collection class (which, incidentally, wraps a dynamic array), I want this same functionality.

How does Visual Studio know how many elements to display in the watch window for `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2012 and later, the answer is Debugger Type Visualizers.
[See the Visual Studio team blog for the 2012 version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx)
and for the nitty gritty details (if you want to implement custom ones) check the MSDN docs.

Answer (score 6):

There is a file called `autoexp.dat` which the debugger uses to interpret custom types. It's not officially meant to be edited, but we have used it in-house for collection types and it works okay. There are some rough edges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf0e8s14.aspx

Comment: Just keep in mind that autoexp.dat is not supported by VS2012, there is a new visualizer mechanism for 2012.